# Why adal is not working with angular 4 in Asp.Net Core solution?

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-api-apps

I runned an `npm install --save @adal-angular4`. Package is successfully added in node module.

But when typing:

```
import { Adal5Service, Adal5HTTPService } from 'adal-angular5'
```

I get the following errors:

> adal-angular4 has no exported member adal4service adal-angular4 has no exported member adal4HttpService

I also installed `ng2-adal`, it is visible in `package.json`, in nodemodule an din npm dependencies folder in solution.

But when typing `import { AdalService } from 'ng2-adal'`
I get the following error:

> cannot find module ng2-adal

Any solution for this please ?

Comment: You installed `adal-angular4` but import from `adal-angular5`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of Adal with angular5. https://github.com/jcmontx/angular5-adal-example.  I have tested it.  All just works well. It also has code "import { Adal5Service, Adal5HTTPService } from 'adal-angular5';" in app.module.ts.

[Screenshot after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFpMD.png)